# Can't install packages with ./sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to follow along in the essential-play book.

I am on this section of the book: [git](https://github.com/underscoreio/essential-play-code/tree/exercises/chapter2-calc).

My understanding at this point is that I should run ./sbt.sh to install all the packages required (this worked for chapter 1). However, this is the output:

```
./sbt.sh 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project/}chapter2-time-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.6
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/build-link/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/build-link/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/build-link/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/build-link/2.3.6/build-link-2.3.6.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.6
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-exceptions/2.3.6/play-exceptions-2.3.6.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.6
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.6/routes-compiler_2.10-2.3.6.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;2.3.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;2.3.6
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support-210_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support-210_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support-210_2.10/2.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-run-support-210_2.10/2.3.6/sbt-run-support-210_2.10-2.3.6.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cc8d2761242b072cedb0a04cb39435[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.6: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.6: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.6: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;2.3.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:build-link:2.3.6
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.3.6 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:chapter2-time-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-exceptions:2.3.6
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.3.6 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:chapter2-time-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:routes-compiler_2.10:2.3.6
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.3.6 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:chapter2-time-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-run-support-210_2.10:2.3.6
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.3.6 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/me/Dropbox/essential-play-code/chapter2-time/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:chapter2-time-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.6: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.6: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.6: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;2.3.6: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1439)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1435)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1470)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1468)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1473)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1467)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1490)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1417)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;2.3.6: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

None of these options seems useful (I tried last and it didn't work).

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: For other's dealing with the same problem I haven't run into other sections that have the same issue. So this could probably just be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sbt doesn't know where to find some of libraries needed to compile your project.
You will need to add resolvers to your build.sbt:

```
resolvers ++=
Seq("Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
"Typesafe maven releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/")
```

Comment: Try to add those lines in project/plugins.sbt instead of build.sbt. Does it help?